# Gibbs sampling Bayesian conditional distribution for mean of a Normal distribution

Tags: distributions, self-study, bayesian, markov-process, gibbs

first post here in CV. I'm currently working on a textbook exercise on Gibbs Sampling and got stuck on naming the distribution for one of the conditional distributions.

#### Question

Consider a normal model:
$$x_i \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2) \text{ for } i=1,...,N$$
Assuming the prior
$$p(\mu,\sigma^2)\propto\frac{1}{\sigma^2}$$
Derive & write the name & parameters for the conditional distribution $p(\mu|\sigma^2,x_1,...,x_{N})$

#### Attempt so far

I've calculated the joint pdf as
$$p(x_1,...,x_N,\mu,\sigma^2)\propto (\frac{1}{\sigma^2})^{N/2+1}\exp{(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_1^N{(x_i-\mu)^2})}$$
So the conditional pdf is:
$$p(\mu|\sigma^2,x_1,...,x_{N}) \propto p(x_1,...,x_N,\mu,\sigma^2) \\
\propto (\frac{1}{\sigma^2})^{N/2+1}\exp{(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_1^N{(x_i-\mu)^2})} \\
\propto \exp{(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_1^N{(x_i-\mu)^2}}) \\
\propto \exp{(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_1^N{(x_i^2-2\mu x_i +\mu^2)}}) \\
\propto \exp{(\frac{1}{\sigma^2}(-\frac{N}{2}\mu^2+\mu\sum_1^N{x_i}))} \\
\propto \frac{\exp{(\mu\sigma^{-2}\sum{x_i}})}{\exp{(\mu^2\sigma^{-2}\frac{N}{2}})}
$$

I'm struggling to see what distribution this one is, with respect to $\mu$.

#### My question

What is the name & parameters for a distribution with the pdf of a ratio of 2 exponentials like this:
$$\frac{e^{\alpha x}}{e^{\beta x^2}}$$

Comment: I am wondering how you reached to this conditional distribution. As we know "In statistics, Gibbs sampling or a Gibbs sampler is an MCMC algorithm for obtaining a sequence of observations which are approximated from a specified multivariate probability distribution when direct sampling is difficult". Right? But, you have only one normal distribution here. Why do you use Gibbs sampling here? Why conditional distribution for $\mu$ as the sampling method for taking samples from a distribution? not like a likelihood method to estimate a parameter of the distribution.